# How do I test the title of a page from an RSpec view spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, title, rspec2

I'm learning RSpec 2 with Rails 3. In order to set the contents of the  tag in the layout for each page, I have a helper that can be used to set the title and then return it:

```
def page_title(subtitle=nil)
  if @title.nil?
    @title = ["Site Name"]
  end

  unless subtitle.nil?
    @title << subtitle
  end

  @title.reverse.join " - "
end
```

The helper is called from both the layout, where it returns the title, and the individual views, where it sets the title. Now, I want to test in the view specs that the title is being set correctly. Since the layout is not rendered, I have decided to call page_title from the spec and check that the return value is what I expect it to be. However, this doesn't work, and always just returns "Site Name". What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but you could test the layout directly:

```
require 'spec_helper'
include ApplicationHelper

describe "layouts/application" do
  it "should add subtitle to page title" do
    page_title("Subtitle")
    render
    rendered.should have_selector('title:contains("Subtitle - Site Name")')
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

You could also test that the `page_title` method is called in the view:

```
describe "mycontroller/index" do
  it "should set subtitle" do
    view.should_receive(:page_title).with("Subtitle")
    render
  end
end
```

or you could use a controller test with `render_views`:

```
describe Mycontroller do
  render_views
  it "sets the page title" do
    get :index
    response.body.should contain("Subtitle - Site Name")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was looking for. I'm trying to test that the view is setting the title correctly (by calling page_title) by checking the output of page_title to what I want that page to return. Like, it would be different for each view.

Comment: Well, it wasn't what I was originally looking for, but I have decided to just test it from the controller spec. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this reply helped me to understand that the layouts can be tested as if they were just another view.

Comment: `have_title` matcher can be also be used in capybara/rspec

Answer (score 3):

To check the title of a page in a view spec try:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "controller/view.html.erb" do
  it "renders page title with 'Title | MySite'" do
    render template: "controller/view", layout: "layouts/application"
    rendered.should have_selector("title", text: "Title | MySite")
  end
end
```

Because render is being called outside of the controller, it needs to be told about the layout.