# Rspec view test not working out, help me troubleshoot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing Rspec view tests, and the tests are not passing, but I'm not sure why. In other words there are no errors in the way the test is written, it's just that the expectation is not meeting the result. Would love help troubleshooting here.

In the test below, I initially thought the problem was that the link I'm looking for is in the navbar in the application layout. So following advice from this post: [getting Rspec view specs to render application layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548838/getting-rspec-view-specs-to-render-application-layout), I explicitly called which template and layout to render. However, the right link still cannot be found.

The href tag that I've written is copied directly from the inspect element on the actual page. I have also tried to write the new_request_path that the routes gives me, and that didn't work either.

Thanks for any help!

RSpec View test code:

```
describe 'signups/new.html.erb' do

it 'displays link to request pages not signup page' do
  assign(:signup, FactoryGirl.build(:signup))
  render template: "signups/new", layout: "layouts/application"
  rendered.should have_link(href: "/new")
end
end
```

FYI, Inspect Element:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="/new">Make a new request</a>
```

FYI, Routes:

```
 get 'new', to: 'requests#new', as: 'new_request'
```

FYI, the application layout being rendered:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_path %>">Home</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= new_request_path %>">Make a new request</a>
```

I don't see the need to post anything from the new template being rendered since hte test is looking only inside the application layout. (But it's not a layout based view test, because 1) I'm testing pages as a whole and there are different flash messages triggered in the layout and because 2) other tests that I'm writing [similarly stuck but I think I can figure them out if I get help on one] look at the actual new template)

Comment: have this  `config.render_views` on rspec config?

Comment: Why is this a test for the signups/new.html.erb view if you're actually testing the layout?

Comment: @Derek It's not a layout based view test, because 1) I'm testing pages as a whole and there are different flash messages triggered in the layout and because 2) other tests that I'm writing [similarly stuck but I think I can figure them out if I get help on one] look at the actual new template

Comment: @Monk_Code render_views doesn't seem to work for me... I have tried to set it globally in the config, and locally spec file with just render_views, and both, and then written the simplest test on the page itself (not layout) that definitely should pass and it keeps failing. I also found on Stack Overflow a mention of needing to include this in the config: config.include RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering, so I tried that and it didn't work either. The whole reason for why I'm doing View tests like this is because the Controller tests can't render views

Comment: @james : then this is a controller spec or even a feature spec

Comment: @Derek, any idea how to incorporate it into the controller spec if render_views is not working per my comment above? Because I agree I would love to integrate... I have a suspicion that between render_views not working and the view specs not working, maybe there's just something wrong with the view config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat figured this out, here are some short hand notes:

1. Render_view in controller never worked, I just removed it
   completely (at least controller tests pass!)
2. So terrible, but reason view tests weren't passing is because my
   model is named Request so my variables were @request, which
   apparently is a class already, so there was a name conflict. I
   basically had to change every instance of @request to @requestrecord
3. There were indeed some syntax errors in the tests. have_selector('csstag') MUST be prefixed with either a . for css class or # for css id. As well, have_link MUST take a name of link, e.g., have_link("Home", href: root_path). If latter can be changed, that'd be great, because I think it's worrisome to have a hard written title of the link, which can easily change.
4. In two views that were tested, the first lines of code in the actual view were if/then statements testing for errors in form submission (and then flashing up an appropriate message) of a certain variable. This tripped up the view because in isolation, these variables were never defined. So in the tests, I had to always add a before block that just passed through some arbitrary data for the variable.